# Java Spring: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource to Keycloak with 2 localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am trying to connect keycloak for a react-python app via a spring security authentication app service.

localhost:3000 react-python application that use the authentication service (spring-java application) in localhost:80. Then localhost:80 will config with keycloak server in localhost:4000

**What I have tested:**

***---------Trying access :80 directly to :4000 (keycloak) -  **successful**:***

**Response Header**

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2022 22:59:21 GMT

Expires: 0

Keep-Alive: timeout=60

Location: http://localhost:4000/auth/realms/aip-realm/protocol/openid-
connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id...

Pragma: no-cache

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

**Request Header**

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2022 22:59:21 GMT

Expires: 0

Keep-Alive: timeout=60

Location: http://localhost:4000/auth/realms/aip-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id...

Pragma: no-cache

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

***-------Trying access :3000 via :80 to connect keycloak :4000 - **CORS ERROR**:***

GET http://localhost:4000/oauth2/authorization/keycloak net::ERR_FAILED 302
I have the error message.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:80/oauth2/authorization/keycloak' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**1.The first one is still good until second redirect.**

**Type: XHR/Redirect**

**Response Header**

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Max-Age: 180

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

Date: Sun, 18 Dec 2022 09:15:55 GMT
Expires: 0

Location: http://localhost:80/oauth2/authorization/keycloak

Pragma: no-cache

**Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate**
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

**Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9

Connection: keep-alive

Cookie: JSESSIONID=1B5EE995A0031DC34E6860027398CD68

Host: localhost:3000

Referer: http://localhost:3000/

sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"

sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0

sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

**Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors**
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

**2. Then the keycloak error request (CORS Errors):**

**Type: XHR**

**Response Headers**

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

Date: Sun, 18 Dec 2022 09:15:55 GMT

Expires: 0

Keep-Alive: timeout=60

Location: http://localhost:4000/auth/realms/aip-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id...

Pragma: no-cache

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=185783DD1403AC2D6CC222350D842CD8; Path=/; HttpOnly

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

**Request Headers**

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9

Connection: keep-alive

**Host: localhost:80**

**Origin: http://localhost:3000**

**Referer: http://localhost:3000/**

sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"

sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0

sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

**Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors**

Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Here is the config Oauth2:

```
http.oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        // Specific entry point for failed authentication
        .authenticationEntryPoint(getEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());

http.addFilterAfter(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
...
```

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

```
private AuthenticationEntryPoint getEntryPoint() {
    return (request, response, authException) -> {
        if (authException != null) {
            response.sendRedirect("/oauth2/authorization/keycloak");
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        }
    };
}
```

Anyone have some experience with this issue ? :)

I would like when trying access :3000 it's still redirect to keycloak :4000 via authen service :80.

Comment: Have you added `http://localhost:3000` to Web Origins in the settings of your Keycloak client through the admin console?

Comment: Yes I tried putting localhost:3000 and * in Web Origins, and it still doesn't work. The onlyway seem to work is to redirect from react app with localtion.href assignment, that I don't want because of the consitency of authen service

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try @CrossOrigin annotation.

[More information about a CORS support in Spring Framework you can find on spring.io website](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Comment: I have tried and seem it's not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).